# using gcnew as a copy constructor

Tags: c++-cli, clr, default-copy-constructor

i know that `gcnew` is used to allocate managed memory.
i also didn't find any `System::String(System::String ^)`constructor.
normally if you want to copy a `System::String` class you will use something like

```
System::String ^s1 = gcnew System::String("a");
System::String ^s2 = System::String::Copy(s1);
```

but what about this?

```
System::String ^s1 = gcnew System::String("a");
System::String ^s2 = gcnew System::String(s1);
```

Comment: In .net the = assigns a new reference to existing object. String in .net are allo immutabile.  So You need only string s1=s2 to copy. The only difference is if You use ReferenceEquals Vs Equals to compare them

Comment: i can't find a reference for immutable. i think immutability is programmed and it is not a .net standard.

Comment: System::String was carefully designed to ensure that copying is never necessary.  None of its members allows altering the string content.  The garbage collector ensures that one instance is always good enough to serve any need.  Basic advantages are that you can always pass a string object to another method and be sure that it can never change.  And that it is automatically thread-safe.  And that it does not need a copy constructor.

Comment: it is useful when you want to use pin_ptr<const wchar_t> to pin a small string that is a member of a class without pinning the whole class. you copy it and pin the copy string instead. this is why i am trying to find out if this code copies the string for me or just assigns the handles or it differs in different compilers.

Comment: How does whether 1 or many other fields or variables refer to the same String object make a difference? Are you trying to break the immutability contract?

Comment: no, i am trying to make another string similar to the previous because i need one that is not a member of my class so i can pin the copy without pinning the whole class. i have nothing to do with immutability. i just want to know what this syntax does. because gcnew is supposed to allocate a new space. but the question is does it allocate a new managed space based on the previous one or not.

Comment: For a string value, pin the string value referenced by whatever expression yields it (variable, field, x->ToString(), whatnot) using PtrToStringChars as the initializer. Use the pointer until the pin is released. Then don't use the pointer anymore

Comment: too many calls ToString() slows down the performance, plus i don't ToString() because the values i am sending are managed texts from windows forums to fast native functions. using a pointer and then not using it is weak, a pin_ptr is implicitly convertible to native pointer and it is much safer over the really small performance disadvantage( since i am managing longs texts not short texts and i don't need to call it much). i also don't have any problem finding a way, i just can't find a reference that answers my question. because this gcnew construction is allowed for System::String only!

Comment: I don't understand why the second snippet would work. But it does work. Can anyone explain? I'm starting a bounty yea!!

Comment: as of immutability, just google for .NET string class. That Microsoft page is official. You should have an understanding about ref vs value stuff too. @alangab